# how to do group by bar plot in plotly in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
   name      year     month     volume
   SSI       2016      01       123
   SSI       2016      02       23 
   SSI       2016      03       1234
   SSI       2016      04       1253
   SSI       2016      04       144
   SSI       2016      05       167
   SSII      2016      01       1112
   SSII      2016      02       234
   SSII      2016      03       154
   SSII      2016      04       143
   SSII      2016      04       144
   SSII      2016      05       167
```

How I want to plot is on `x axis` I want all the `name` and group by `year` and on y axis `volume`. 
How can I do it ion plotly?

Comment: check the ggplot2 package. Perfect for that. `ggplot(aes(Name, value)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~year)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your data to include 2017 year for few records

```
df <- read.table(text = " name      year     month     volume
   SSI       2016      01       123
                 SSI       2016      02       23 
                 SSI       2016      03       1234
                 SSI       2017      04       1253
                 SSI       2017      04       144
                 SSI       2017      05       167
                 SSII      2016      01       1112
                 SSII      2016      02       234
                 SSII      2016      03       154
                 SSII      2017      04       143
                 SSII      2017      04       144
                 SSII      2017      05       167", header = T)

g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(year), y = volume, group = name, fill = name)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
ggplotly(g)
```